# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!} =0$

Tags: real-analysis

I think proving $\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2} sin^n x\, dx=0$ is helpful as $I_n=\frac{(n-1)!!}{n!!}$ when n is odd . However it seems difficult for me to come up with such a integral.

Is there any wise idea to solve this problem？Thanks.

I mean how to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!} =0$

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Why not just use the fact that $\sin^n{(x)}$ converges pointwise to zero on $[0,\pi/2)$?

Answer (score 1):

Write your original sequence $I_n$ as $I_n=\prod_{3 \leq k \leq 2n+1,\,k=1[2]}{\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)}$.

Note that $1-1/k \leq 1-1/(k-1)$, thus $I_n^2 \leq \prod_{2 \leq k \leq 2n+1}{\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)}=\frac{1}{2n+1} \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If you look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial), you will see that
$$\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!} \approx \sqrt{\pi n}$$ Just adapt it to your problem.